java.lang.NoSuchMethodError after uplifting Spring data JPA jars to v3.3.0
after I uplifted spring data jpa and commons jar to version 3.3.0 of our product, I got this error.
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void com.org.application.server.services.workorder.database.dao.OfflineConfigWorkOrder._persistence_checkFetchedForSet(java.lang.String)'
    at com.org.application.server.services.workorder.database.dao.OfflineConfigWorkOrder._persistence_set_ocConfigId(OfflineConfigWorkOrder.java) ~

For this issue NoSuchMethodError I found that the method was present during compile time but somehow is missing during runtime.
I have checked that I am using the correct jars and all the dependencies given are correct.
I had already uplifted spring boot to its latest version and when I added the spring data jpa and commons jars I got this issue and I used Apache Ant to build the project
I would like to know what would be causing this issue and how can I solve this..
Edit: For us currently it's not possible to move away or upgrade ant or introduce Ivy for dependency management due to time constraints.
Update:
One thing that I want to mention is that when I turned off weaving in our properties file then the issue got fixed even with the latest version of data-jpa jars... So I wanted to know whether setting weaving to false is the right way to move forward or is there any fix that we can do while weaving is set to true...
Current Set of EL jars we are using:
jakarta.persistence-2.2.3.jar
org.eclipse.persistence.antlr-2.7.13.jar
org.eclipse.persistence.asm-9.6.0.jar
org.eclipse.persistence.core-4.0.2.jar
org.eclipse.persistence.jpa-4.0.2.jar
org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jpql-4.0.2.jar
org.eclipse.persistence.moxy-4.0.2.jar

and this used to work for us until this spring data jars uplift

Please add your dependencies what did you upgrade and how?

I have added the jars that are non-optional dependencies for spring-data-commons like spring core, context, jpa, asm and others... and I have used apache ant to build the project

What was asked is that you edit the question to add the details of your dependencies and what did you change. Since you are using Ant you don't manage dependencies with the build tool. That is probably causing issues. Ant is an old tool that is seldom used. Why are you using Ant to build the project?

Manually cobling together dependencies is not something to do in this day and age. Only updating Spring Data jars and trying to find the combination that works is a tedious job as you probably need to update Spring as well and if you are unlucky Hibernate and other dependencies as well. It is not just slap in some new jars and it works. I would strongly suggest to use Maven / Gradle for this instead of ant. Ifyou cannot leave ant at least introduce Ivy to manage your dependencies.

For us currently it's not possible to move away or upgrade ant... I just wanted to point out one thing that once I set weaving to false in eclipseLink properties I didn't face this issue. I am only getting this error while weaving is set to true... now I wanted to know whether setting weaving is correct way to move forward ??
